# Stop a player when another starts

Tags: php, javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have multiple players on the same page (flash as3), but I would like, that when a player is playing, stops, when another player begins to play...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches:

1) Set up a `LocalConnection` between the different players and have one call the other when it's finished playing. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html for more info on the `LocalConnection` class.

2) Using `ExternalInterface`, SWF1 calls some JavaScript on your page to tell it it's finished. The JavaScript keeps track of which SWF is next to play (SWF2), and tells it to start. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

On the function you call on the "Play" button listener...

*(lets say this is the player1 play button that calls startPlay1)*

```
player1PlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPlay1);

function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    movieClip_1.play();
    movieClip_2.stop();
    movieClip_3.stop();
    movieClip_4.stop();
}
```

and so on for the other players.

and if you want them to start over it is of course...
    movieClip_4.gotoAndStop(1);

Hope this helps! Good luck.